# Generalization of sub-additivity

Tags: probability-theory

**strong text**I dont know how to start or construct on how to prove this. If i have a $(\Omega, \Beta ,  P)$ as probabilty space. How cn i show that for events $B_i \subset A_i$, this generalization of sub-additivity: 
P( union of $A_i$) - P( union of $B_i$) $\leq$ $\Sigma (P(A_i) - P(B_i)) $

Comment: Hint: apply subadditivity to the the sets $A_i\setminus B_i$.

Comment: Are the $A_i$'s need to be independent?

Answer (score 1):

By subadditivity, we have
$$
P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\setminus B_i\right)\le \sum_{i\in I} P(A_i\setminus B_i)=\sum_{i\in I} P(A_i)-P(B_i)
$$

By $A_i\setminus B_i$ I mean $A_i\cap B_i^c$. We also have that $(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i)\setminus(\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i)\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\setminus B_i$, so that
$$
P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i\setminus B_i\right)\ge P\left(\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)\setminus\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i\right)=P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i\right)-P\left(\bigcup_{i\in I}B_i\right)
$$
Combining the above two lines gives you the inequality you want.

Comment: Yes thank you sir @mikeEarnest.

Comment: I have doubts in $P( \bigcup A_i - \bigcup B_i )= P( \bigcup A_i) - P( \bigcup B_i)$ @mikeEarnest.

Comment: @mogs This holds because $\bigcup B_i\subseteq \bigcup A_i$: if an element is in at least one $B_i$, it will be in at least one $A_i$. Whenever $C\subseteq D$, we have $P(D) = P(C) + P(D\setminus C)$, so that $P(D\setminus C)=P(D)-P(C)$.